# Convert Boolean Value with true into an array in Angular4 (Typescript)

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, boolean

I am getting a set of boolean values from my microservice.

```
   "mon": true,
   "tues": false,
   "wed": false,
   "thurs": true,
   "fri": false,
   "sat": true,
   "sun": false,
```

And I need to convert the values with boolean value true to an array like
following:

`options = ['mon', 'thurs', 'sat']`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `filter` on the object keys for those days key:

```js
var day = {
  "mon": true,
  "tues": false,
  "wed": false,
  "thurs": true,
  "fri": false,
  "sat": true,
  "sun": false
};

var res = Object.keys(day).filter(key => day[key]);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @ChanYoongHon glad to help. You can tick mark the answer if it was helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the keys:

```js
const obj = {
    "mon": true,
    "tues": false,
    "wed": false,
    "thurs": true,
    "fri": false,
    "sat": true,
    "sun": false,
};
const options = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key]);

console.log(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way with entries and array destructure

```js
let day = {
  "mon": true,
  "tues": false,
  "wed": false,
  "thurs": true,
  "fri": false,
  "sat": true,
  "sun": false
};

let result = Object.entries(day).filter(([key, state]) =>state).map(([key]) => key);

console.log(result);
```